# How to create multiples directories fom a vector?

Tags: r, directory

I would like to create multiples directories from a vector.

**I have this vector:**

```r
vector <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

**And I have tried this:**

```r
dir.create(c("A/B/C/", vector))
```

**But I didn't get the expected directories:**

- A/B/C/1
- A/B/C/2
- A/B/C/3

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste` and use a loop `sapply` as the `?dir.create` documentation says

> path - a character vector containing a single path name

```
sapply(paste0("A/B/C/", vector), dir.create)
```

#### data

```
vector = c(1, 2, 3)
```